# How to create a profile page for users?

Tags: profiles

Is there way to create a profile page for all users( including who have not written any post)?

Ex1: example.com/profile/alex >> ex2: example.com/profile/john

I need to do something like this.

Comment: What had you tried? I vaguely remember similar question being asked before, search through the site. Please note that "I need" format doesn't work too well for questions here, we will help you figure things out, but usually won't up and do it for you. :)

Comment: @Rarst What I have done is I edited the archive.php file using if(is_author() condition. It was successful for all authors (example.com/author/username). But it doesn't work users who have not write a post.

Comment: Please add that code and details to your question. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, its work for me

add your functions.php

```
add_action('init', function(){
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->author_base = 'profile';
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
});
```

and create author.php in your theme directory.

example;

```
<?php
$author = get_user_by('slug', get_query_var('author_name')); 
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($author);
```